# Display flex with CSS order

Tags: html, css

How can I make the primary box move to the top row, above the other two boxes? I thought that I can use the CSS "order" but it doesn't seems to work.

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.primary {
  order:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item"> Box 1 </div>
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="item"> Box 2 with medium width</div>
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="item primary"> Box 3 with larger width content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: order property move primary item beore 2 and 3. It doesn't make primary item at top and item2-3 below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex-wrap: wrap to make multi row layout using flex. and use flex-basis:100% to make primary item 100%.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.primary {
  order:-1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> Box 1 </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item"> Box 2 with medium width</div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="item primary"> Box 3 with larger width content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `flex-basis: 100%;` to the class `.primary`. This makes it use up a whole row by itself.

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
}

.border {
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.primary {
  order:-1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item"> Box 1 </div>
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="item"> Box 2 with medium width</div>
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="item primary"> Box 3 with larger width content</div>
</div>
```